# How to integrate : $\frac{-\pi}{2} \int^{-1}_{1} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to integrate :

$$\frac{-\pi}{2} \int^{-1}_{1} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$

Can the limit be $1$ to $-1$ as we know the integral result is $\tan^{-1}x$

Please let me know the details to tackle such integrals,

Can we use this property somehow,

Property : $\int^{a}_{-a}f(x)dx = 2\int^a_0f(x)dx$

Comment: This is an elementary antiderivative. Lookup a table or try $t=\tan x$.

Comment: $ x= \tan \theta$

Comment: Following the substitution $x=\tan(\theta)$, use the identity $\tan^2(\theta)+1=\sec^2(\theta)$

Answer (score 1):

We have this integral:
$$\frac{-\pi}{2}\int_{1}^{-1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx=\pi\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx$$
After making the substitution that I outlined in my comment*, your integral becomes
$$\pi \arctan(x)\,\biggr|_0^{1}=\boxed{\pi\arctan(1)}$$

*during the evaluation of the integral, use the fact that $\frac{d}{d\theta}\tan(\theta)=\sec^2(\theta)$.